# Find c for which tangent line meets $c/(x+1)$

Tags: calculus

Here is the problem: 
Determine $c$ so that the straight line joining $(0, 3)$ and
$(5, -2)$ is tangent to the curve $y = c/(x + 1)$.

So, what I know: the line connecting the points is $y=-x+3$.
I need to find a value for c such that the derivative of $c/(x+1)$ can be $-x+3$.
I took the derivative of $c/(x+1)$, and found a line via point-slope form, so 
$$y-3=-\frac{cx}{(x+1)^2}  \quad \Rightarrow \quad y=-\frac{cx}{(x+1)^2} + 3 $$

At this point the tangent line is $y=-x+3$.
So, $-x = (-cx/(x+1)^2)$. From there, I can conclude $c=x^2+2x+1$. How do I conclude, without looking at a graph, what value of $x$ to choose? I know from the answer that at $x=1$, $c=4$, and the tangent line meets the curve at that point $x=1$. But how would I determine this?

Answer (score 0):

from $\frac{c}{x+1} = -x+3$ and $-\frac{c}{(x+1)^2} = -1$ , you got $x+1=-x+3$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Here are two curves whose slope are supposed to be equal:
$$
y=-x + 3
$$
and
$$
\frac{c}{x+1}=y
$$

equating the slopes of both of curves,

we have
$$
-1=\frac{-c}{(x+1)^2}
$$

this gives you
$$
(x+1)^2=c\implies x=-1\pm \sqrt c
$$

note that from here we need $c$ should be non-negative. i.e. $c\geq 0$

Now at $x=-1\pm \sqrt c$ both curves touch each other. So,
$$
-x + 3=\frac{c}{(x+1)}
$$
at $x=-1\pm \sqrt c$.

Solve this equation replacing $x=-1\pm \sqrt c$. and you will have value of $c$ you want.

Comment: thx. The key step, I think, is equating the slope of both curves.

Comment: Always Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

A line will either intersect the curve **at more than one points(intersection), or it will touch at a single point(tangent), or it wont intersect at all**. In all the cases if you solve the equations of the **line and the curve simultaneously** you will get the solutions which reflect the above three conditions.

Now you straight line is $$y=-x+3$$and the curve is $$y=\frac{c}{x+1}$$
which is a hyperbola.
Solve these two equations to get the intersection point(s).

$$-x+3=\frac{c}{x+1}$$
$$x^2 -2x+(c-3)=0$$
Solve the equation to get $$x=1\pm\sqrt{4-c}$$
therefore $$y=2\mp\sqrt{4-c}$$
The points of intersection of these two curves are $A(1+\sqrt{4-c},2-\sqrt{4-c})$ and $B(1-\sqrt{4-c},2+\sqrt{4-c})$.
Now the thing is a line and a hyperbola can intersect at **maximum 2 points and those 2 points are known**. Since the line is a tangent to the hyperbola, we can equate both the coordinates. In other words, **the line should touch the hyper bola at one point for that both the points must have the same value**.
Equating the x and y coordinates of A and B respectively we will get:
$$1+\sqrt{4-c}=1-\sqrt{4-c}$$
$$1+\sqrt{4-c}=1-\sqrt{4-c}$$
Only one condition:
$$\sqrt{4-c}=0$$
which means $c=4$ and hence, if you put this back in the value of $x$ you get only one point $x=1\pm\sqrt{4-c}=1\pm\sqrt{0}=1$ **which proves that actually the line is a tangent.**

The $y$ value is $y=2$ So the point of contact is $(1,2)$

Now another check whether our calculation is correct or not, **calculate the slopes separately of the line and hyperbola at the contact point $(1,2)$**.
Slope of line at $(1,2)$ is $-1$.
Slope of line passing through the point $(1,2)$ is :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}|_{(x=1,y=2)} = -\frac{c}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{4}{4} = -1$$

So we verified that the line which touches the hyperbola has the same slope as that of the line that we came up with.

Check this online plotting tool https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en put the input and output functions to see the plot it will help you visualize it.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of these questions is "equating the slopes", i.e.,  $m_1=m_2$: $m_1$ is the slope of the given line which you already computed here as $m_1=-1$ and $m_2$ is the derivative of the curve function at the point of tangency, which is the slope of the tangent line.

Since the derivative of the curve is $m_2=y'=-\frac{c}{(x+1)^2}$, at the point of tangency $P=(x_0,y_0)$, we have $-\frac{c}{(x_0+1)^2}=-1$ and hence $c$ must be non-negative and 1) $x_0=\sqrt{c}-1$ or 2) $x_0=-\sqrt{c}-1$. Let's consider the two options separetely.

If $x_0=\sqrt{c}-1$, then from the equation of the curve, $y_0=\sqrt{c}$ and hence $P=(\sqrt{c}-1,\sqrt{c})$. But, $P$ also lies on the line connecting the given points which you found as $y=-x+3$. So, $\sqrt{c}=-(\sqrt{c}-1)+3\implies2\sqrt{c}=4\implies c=4.$

If $x_0=-\sqrt{c}-1$, then from the equation of the curve, $y_0=-\sqrt{c}$ and hence $P=(-\sqrt{c}-1,-\sqrt{c})$. So, $-\sqrt{c}=-(-\sqrt{c}-1)+3\implies\sqrt{c}=-2$. No solution, since $\sqrt{c}>0$ by definition. This convention is a little tricky and not practical. Since, you may argue that there is a solution again and it is $c=4$.

Anyway, $c=4$. And also $P=(1,2).$ Also, in my opinion, using subscripts like $x_0, y_0$ is not practical in tests.